# The Get method is not supported for this route .supported methods:POST in prudiction

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce, rich-text-editor

in my Laravel app when using rich text editor "TinyMCE" and submit the form
get an error
**The Get method is not supported for this route .supported methods:POST**
this error just in **production** and when style my text in TinyMCE.

I try all steps to know the error reason, I found that the problem occurs when styling any text in TinyMCE just but if the text hasn't any style the request is done naturally

Answer (score 0):

Check your routes/web.php file and make sure the route you're submitting to supports the get method or you could change post to any.

Ex.
Route::**any**($uri, $callback);

Comment: thanks for the solution, but when change route to any, the request goes to the controller but without data! , when returning $request->all() get empty array[], hint: this error just get when adding any style to rich text ex: for example when making text in the center but in the normal text doesn't get any error

Answer (score -1):

an error was in production, I called my shared host to disable ModSecurity Block to  make me use any style or any reserved words from host

this message from my host support

> There was a ModSecurity block. ModSecurity is an Apache module that works as a web application firewall. It blocks known exploits and provides protection from a range of attacks against web applications. However, sometimes, mod_security may incorrectly determine that a certain request is malicious, while it is actually legitimate. In such a situation, we can whitelist the triggered mod_security rule on the server, so that you can bypass the block.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30560126)